# ¿Cómo cambiar de activity al presionar un elemento de un Custom Adapter en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, activity, customadapter

Tengo un error el cual es el siguiente:

> Unable to find explicit activity class, have you declared this
>   activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

EL programa funciona perfectamente, el problema es que al presionar un botón que tiene cada elemento del Adaptador Personalizado para cambiar de `activity` me sale el error mostrado anteriormente.

esto tengo dentro del boton del elemento:

```
Button btnEditar = (Button) contenedor.findViewById(R.id.btnEditar);
    btnEditar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Intent ventana = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Editar.class);
                ventana.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(ventana);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje definido en el LogCat indica el problema, no se encuentra la activity ya que no esta declarada dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` :

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   explicit activity class
>   {...};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

En ocasiones agregamos alguna Activity a nuestro proyecto pero estas no se registran automáticamente en el AndroidManifest.xml, **agrega la actividad dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` para que quede registrada en tu aplicacion.**

```
  <application
     ...
      ...
      <activity android:name=".Editar"/>
  </application>
```